# How to copy files from zip archive to the clipboard

Tags: winapi, clipboard

[This useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54093102/6282716) shows how one can copy the given files to the clipboard. Is it possible in a similar way to copy files from a zip archive, as Explorer does? One can unzip the archive to a temporary folder and copy from there, but then there is a problem of subsequent deletion of the files, since it is not known when they can be deleted (the program may already be closed at this time).

Comment: Zip file contents aren't real files. To put them on the clipboard directly (rather than via a temporary file) you need to actually be able to extract the contents yourself, and provide an [IDataObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-idataobject) that presents the [CFSTR_FILECONTENTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard#cfstr_filecontents) data format that lets other apps read the data stream.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter This solves the problem of temporary files, but not the problem of closing the program. When the process ends, the `IDataObject` will be destroyed, right?

Comment: Theoretically an object on the clipboard can outlive the program that put it there.

Comment: Yes, but if the object refers to a zip that doesn't exist anymore then the object should be removed from the clipboard.