# how to copy large files (i.e. videos) into clipboard using WINAPI with C++

Tags: c++, winapi, copy, clipboard

I have written an application which is capable of copying text and pictures to the clipboard. But it seems that copying other files, videos for example, aren't copied to the clipboard directly. I want to paste these files, using ctrl + v, after I have copied them. Which WINAPI function do I have to use?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile

Comment: copy/paste files https://stackoverflow.com/q/25708895/4603670

Comment: See [Shell Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard) and [Handling Shell Data Transfer Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/datascenarios) on MSDN. There are several different clipboard formats that could be used for this task. However, why are you using the clipboard to transfer larges amount of data? What is the use-case here? There may be a better solution.