# How to use file2clip with csc.exe

Tags: c#, cmd

I would like to ask how to use csc.exe with file2clip.cs in command line because I could not figure it out how to place arguments as paths for the file. The C# code copy the file onto clipboard and needs argument for the selected file path. I have no idea what syntax I need to use after the C# file to specify argument with the path.

[How to copy/cut a file (not the contents) to the clipboard in Windows on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189010/how-to-copy-cut-a-file-not-the-contents-to-the-clipboard-in-windows-on-the-com)

```
csc.exe file2clip.cs {c:\IFRToolLog.txt}
```

sent error message ->

```
error CS2001: Source file '(c:\IFRToolLog.txt)' could not be found
```

Comment: Please show your full command line and make clear where input ends and output begins. Just copy your console's contents into a code block.

Comment: Why do you append `{c:\IFRToolLog.txt}`?

Comment: The c# code copy the file onto clipboard, but having no experience using csc.exe I have no idea what syntax I need to specify the argument for the file path.

Comment: You can also just download the exe. You're mixing up compiling the executable and running it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have no experience how to use csc.exe but I expected we can use as .exe with arguments.

Comment: Does `TYPE thefile.txt | clip.exe` do what you want?