# Copy object from an external applicaton and paste into aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an custom developed application procured from a vendor. I am able to do a Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C in this application and Ctrl+V into Word or Pbrush. This gets pasted as an image. But I am trying to do the same onto ASPX Picture Box it does nothing. I have used the code from [ASP Snippets](https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/382984/Paste-image-from-clipboard-using-JavaScript-in-ASPNet/) for achieving this. It does not paste anything in to the picture box. I have also checked [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097664/c-sharp-cut-copy-paste-objects) but this talks about copying C# objects as per my understanding

I have opened clipboard using the WindowsKey+ V. This shows all the historical copied image and text from previous restart but not the copied object from the vendor procured application.

Kindly suggest / help / advice me on this

Answer (score 0):

A image box, or picture box of some sort will not allow a cut + paste of an image.

However note how while I am answering this question, I am freely able to cut + paste in a image!

Thus, you need some kind of control on a page that allows/supports/enables pasting in of images.

Normally for reasons of security, this is not allowed.

You have to adopt some type of html text (HTML editor), that allows such opertaions (paste of content).

CKedit is a good possible choice.

I currently use the HTML editor from the ajax toolkit.
And thus I allow this:

[image]

So, in above, I allow the user(s) to paste in text, or as above shows, a image.

Now, when I display a Radiobutton list, I can drive the user choices from above.

So, above when user hits save becomes this:

[image]

And now I can use the above "list" of choices say like this:

[image]

So, allowing user to paste in "content" for parts of your website, or in above example say enter choices, but those choices allow users to paste in text (and/or graphics) means that your site can be driven by user supplied content.).

So, in both screen caps above, the first one is a editor that lets those doing the "issue tracking" create new "issues", and we allow graphics as part of that process.

And of course for the issue edit, note I was able to type in some text, but ALSO do a screen cpature and cut + paste in the screen shot (ctrl-v).

And note how THIS editor on SO also allows this.

So, in general a image control, or even a text box control does NOT allow pasting in as image + text.

However, the CURRENT editor on SO allows this, and you can in your applications also allow this feature. However, you have to adopt some kind of editor for this process.

As I noted, ckeditor is a popular choice.

https://ckeditor.com/

And the one I was using above is from the ajaxtoolkit for web forms.

https://www.devexpress.com/Products/AJAX-Control-Toolkit/

Both of the above choices are free to use.

Comment: That was a good pointer. Though it did not exactly fit my requirement, it is very much informative. Shall follow this and post here on how I was able to use this to fit my requirement,